# When I switch my oscillating floor fan on it turns the audio off on my PC

Tags: audio, mains, usb-device, pc

When I switch off (not on, or up - there are 3 settings - only down and off) my oscillating floor fan my PC audio drops out. My PC audio is running through a USB midi controller (novation switch.)

To get it back on I have to unplug the USB from the back of the controller and plug it back in again.

What is going on here?  What can I do about it?

Comment: Plug the fan into a different circuit. You have some sort of interference issue. This isn't an electronics design question, but one more suited for the manufacturer, your home electrician, or a number of other possibilities.

Comment: Hmm my floor fan doesn't do this.

Comment: Occasionally, for troubleshooting, I will plug the offending unit into an unplugged UPS unit to provide line voltage. The unit is now floating and there is no wire path for possible interference. If the problem persists, then I know it is RF interference.

Comment: This might help in the diagnosis. When I use my cooker in the kitchen and use the auto-lighting system on the gas stove (click click click, light) I get a huge 'bang' on my audio system when it is turned up. WTF is going on here? Should I call my landlord? Is it a fire risk?

Answer (score 3):

Most likely the fan switch sparks when turning if off, and it sends a burst of electromagnetic interference. That should not happen. But the USB audio interface should handle the interference, so this should not happen. Either the fan emits more than allowed, or the USB device tolerates less than required. Try changing the USB cable, but also other cables can act as an antenna so reorient the devices and cables.

Comment: I had this issue with my TV. Switching any motor in my house (fans, AC, refrigerator) would cause my TV to blank for a moment. I replaced the HDMI cable and the issue disappeared.

Comment: Replacing the HDMI cable didn't help.

Comment: HDMI shielding >100MHz varies widely with cost and construction and cable bends. The arc rise time may reach this bandwidth depending on phase voltage of open time. Triacs can also eliminate this. with zero current cutoff.

Comment: I don't see why would changing a HDMI cable would have an effect on a USB device. It would make more sense to try changing the USB cable.

Comment: The HDMI wires are antennae to 1/4 wavelengths of radiated arcs in the VHF band radiated by arcs from switching off inductive motors of mH range inductance.  The quality shield of shields are a known weakness in poorly design cables in the upper VHF and UHF band, which I have demonstrated for HDMI signals. Yet the shield also blocks ingress to the wires which can couple into the USB ports if nearby and poorly shielded.  Perhaps a better USB cable works better for you. The shield qualities can only be measured with a VNA or  a short arc generator and SA, where the arc gap in um to 1 mm = null f

Comment: When I was Test Eng Mgr, in the 80's I was responsible for ESD Mfg implementation. We had a deionizer on the ceiling towards the door of the clean room where HDD magnetic drives were assembled into HDA's. One day the servo writer was causing bad signals being written to the HDA servo surface. I discovered with a spectrum analyzer that the proximity of the deionizer was radiating broadband noise impulses +/- 20kV 1Hz across a 1cm pin and the spectrum rolled off at the frequency equal to the wavelength of that gap with lower levels of harmonics rising above that f. The servo writer was  4m away.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inductive voltage transient on the shared line getting thru your PC line filter and poor shielding of USB audio cable.

### Updated

I used to get a similar pop sound on non USB audio from bathroom fan when auto off timer switched. Dry contacts do this from near 0 dt from V=LdI/dt so you fix by using a plastic FILM CAPACITOR HV rated >=250V  cap near across switch of 10 nF or so.

10nF=>200kOhms reactance @ 50\60 Hz so < 1mA drain. but must turn off breaker for safety as shock <1mA might scare you if touching the bare wires when switched off.

There are a dozen of different types of plastics used in FILM Capacitor category. Radial or Axial are easiest to work with.  This choice is reduced from thousands of optional choices specifically for snubber use, but almost all film caps work rated higher than line voltage.

https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Cornell-Dubilier-CDE/DPPM20D1K-F?qs=h%252BOCg3uEP1DCFEnc1Jdtjg%3D%3D

Amazon is not the best place to buy these.
Any local hobby electronic shop or distributor to find an equivalent.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSL2lF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The high voltage transient to the motor is a longer loop but when switched off has a slower risetime and less crosstalk EMI.

When switched on the capacitor ESR is low but not zero so current is limited for a very short time and very small loop area in a faraday cage duplex box. (with minor emissions near the 10 MHz band ) If snubber dV/dt=1900V/us=Ic/C and C=10nF, Ic=1900V/us*10nF=19A is it's transient rating.

Comment: wow - thanks for that. Where do I get a  plastic HV rated RF cap near fan across switch of 1nF or less? I have looked on Amazon - not finding anything?

Comment: there are lots of cheaper parts , but  think now 10nF is better = >200kohms at 50\60 Hz and this part is best, but "non-snubber" "FILM caps" rated >250Vac will work. get a dozen  if you choose cheaper parts .... https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Cornell-Dubilier-CDE/DPPM20D1K-F?qs=h%252BOCg3uEP1DCFEnc1Jdtjg%3D%3D